# java classes needed to let the vm work

Tags: java, lua

I'm working with a project that converts Java Bytecode into Lua bytecode, called JVML-JIT (github: Yevano/JVML-JIT). It was created for a popular Minecraft Mod, called ComputerCraft, which adds Lua Computers. It's not my project, but since it's new and doesn't support windows natives (only lua natives) we/I have to code every class with it's natives from the beginning.

It seems Java needs some classes to work, StringBuilder for example. Are there other classes than StringBuilder which the VM needs to work?

Comment: I forget it now, but launch your JVM with the flag that shows all the classes that are loaded. All those that are loaded before yours are probably needed.